# Experimental 'amp-script' throws error: Experiment "amp-script" not enabled."

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to test how powerful the new amp-script feature is. Howver, I am getting this error:

```
    Experiment "amp-script" is not enabled. log.js:187
    "Experiment \"amp-script\" is not enabled." VM14210 v0.js:125
```

I am using the experiment meta tag:

```
    <meta name="amp-experiments-opt-in" content="amp-next-page,amp-script">
```

and I have import the script below it:

```
    <script async custom-element="amp-script" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-script-0.1.js"></script>
```

and in the body I have:

```
    <amp-script layout="container" src="/static/js/ampPiano.js">
     <div id="hello-world"></div>
    </amp-script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make the error go away. Looks like I had to: Enable the experiment via AMP.toggleExperiment('amp-script') in dev console.

I guess this definitely can not be used in production...

Comment: So I am having the same problem. If I run `AMP.toggleExperiment('amp-script')` after the errors not happens, and if I reload the page I get the same error. Any idea's what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that reloading the page resets the window in which case the amp-script is no longer enabled